# Sidekiq multiple workers?

Tags: resque, sidekiq

I have a question regarding Sidekiq. I come from the Resque paradigm, and in the current application I launch one worker per queue, so in the terminal I would do:

```
rake resque:work QUEUE='first'
rake resque:work QUEUE='second'
rake resque:work QUEUE='third'
```

Then, If I want more workers, for example for the third queue, I just create more workers as:

```
rake resque:work QUEUE='third'
```

My question is...

With Sidekiq, how would you start with multiple workers? I know you can do this:

```
sidekiq -q first, -q second, -q third
```

But that would just start one worker that fetches all those queues. So, how would I go to start three workers, and tell each worker to just focus on a particular queue? Also, how would I do that in Heroku?

Comment: Neither of the answers understood the question. I believe the actual answer lies in placing workers on separate processes and specifying which workers go with which queue. Did you figure something out for this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a config file in config/sidekiq.yml :

```
# Sample configuration file for Sidekiq.
# Options here can still be overridden by cmd line args.
#   sidekiq -C config.yml
---
:verbose: true
:pidfile: ./tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
:concurrency: 15
:timeout: 5
:queues:
  - [first, 20]
  - [second, 20]
  - [third, 1]
staging:
  :verbose: false
  :concurrency: 25
production:
  :verbose: false
  :concurrency: 50
  :timeout: 60
```

That way you can configure exactly what you want, and to answer precisely your question the concurrency value is what you are loking for, it defines the number of concurrent workers executed.

More info here : https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options

Answer (score 0):

> So, how would I go to start three workers, and tell each worker to
>   just focus on a particular queue?

You can define on the worker-level in which queue it should be placed via `sidekiq_options`.

To place for example your worker in a queue called *"first"* just define it with

```
class MyWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options :queue => :first
  ...
end
```

Comment: This answer talks about setting up queue per worker, but the question is talking about separating workers and theirs queues on different processes.